# Problems with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

I'm quite new to java, and I'm going to need some help here:

```
package com.game.libs;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Animation {

    private int speed = 0; // defines in how many ticks the animation should go to the next frame
    private int amountOfFrames = 0; //amount of frames in the animation
    private int index = 0; //time value used in the method runAnimation()
    private int currentFrameNumber = 0; //the number of the current frame
    private BufferedImage frames[]; //images in the animation
    private BufferedImage currentFrameImage; //current frame's image
    //13 frame animation
    public Animation(BufferedImage[] img, int fps){
        frames = img;
        amountOfFrames = img.length-1;
        speed = 60/fps;
        for (int i=0;i<img.length-1;i++){
            this.frames[i] = img[i];
        currentFrameNumber = 0;
        currentFrameImage = img[0];
        }
    }

    public void runAnimation(){
        index++;
        if(index > speed){
            index = 0;
            nextFrame();
        }   
    }

    public void nextFrame(){
        currentFrameNumber++;
        if(currentFrameNumber > amountOfFrames)
            currentFrameNumber = 1;
        currentFrameImage = frames[currentFrameNumber]; // THIS IS THE LINE WITH THE ERROR
    }

    public void drawAnimation(Graphics graphics, int x, int y, int offset){
        graphics.drawImage(currentFrameImage, x - offset, y, null);
    }

    public void setCurrentFrame(int currentFrame){
        this.currentFrameNumber = currentFrame;
    }

    public int getCurrentFrameNumber(){
        return currentFrameNumber;
    }

    public int getFps(){
        return speed;
    }

    public void setFps(int fps){
        this.speed = 60/fps;
    }

    public void setFrames(BufferedImage[] img){
        this.frames = img;
        amountOfFrames = img.length;
    }

    public BufferedImage[] getFrames(){
        return frames;
    }
}
```

the error that im getting is array index out bounds. in line 38 (nextFrame method, its in the code)
I've encountered this error before, and I know how to (and tried) to fix it but it says 1 and even 0 are out of bounds...
Plox help, I know this is vague :(, but i tried to make my question (and the code) clear.

remember, im new to java, have had experience with waaaaaaay easier languages/engines but understand quite a bit.

Comment: This `amountOfFrames = img.length;` in the `setFrames` method should also be `amountOfFrames = img.length-1;`.

Comment: You're quite a bit ahead of the pack by understanding the stack trace.  With array bounds the important thing to remember is that arrays are origin-zero, so an array of two elements only has elements 0 and 1 in it.  And of course, an array with zero elements does not even have element 0 in it.  Your check on `currentFrameNumber` probably should be `>=` vs `>`, and maybe should reset to zero.

Comment: @Tom should it? Isn't the amount of elements in `img` equal to the amount of frames since the elements **are** frames

Comment: Either the suggested change or you change this comparison `if(currentFrameNumber > amountOfFrames)`. It is up to you.

Comment: How many images are in your array and what fps are you passing in when you initialize the Animation?

Comment: @dave there is atleast one image in the passed array. Im passing 3 as fps. My game ticks 60 times/second so im it goes to the next frame every 20 ticks (60/3)

Comment: Wouldnt the following changes fix everything: change > to >= and change currentFrameImage = frames[currentFrameNumber] to frames[currentFrameNumber-1]?

Comment: The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException never lies.  If it says there is no element zero then there is no element zero -- the array contains no elements at all.

Comment: @HotLicks I've looked into it I've fixed the problem and this is what it was: I have a function to load the BufferedImages into an array, and you can pass it an anonymous int array containing the sprite numbers loaded by another textures class. I initialized the array to return like this: `returnArray = new BufferedImage[thatArrayArgumentThatIWasTalkingAbout.length-1]` so if you passed it an array with one element it would initialize the array as an array without elements. now that I've removed that -1 and fixed the errors based on your help, I've completed this question. Thank you all. :D

Answer (score 1):

Do note that Java arrays are indexed starting at 0, so it is strange (but not wrong) that in `nextFrame()` you reset `currentFrameNumber` to 1 instead of 0 when it runs over.

Also, it's pretty redundant to use `amountOfFrames` to control the iteration count.  The usual Java idioms involve using the array `.length` directly, maybe

```
    if(currentFrameNumber >= frames.length) {
        currentFrameNumber = 0;
    }
```

None of that really explains the exception you get, though, so there must be more to it.

Or something else to it: perhaps the class that is throwing the exception was not compiled from the same version of the code that you present.

Comment: yes, that was a mistake, i already changed my question, line 38 isnt even in the `runAnimation()` method

Comment: Updated my answer.  Most of it was still relevant.

Comment: It sure was! Thank you

Comment: Also, im setting it back to one because you aren't on the zero'th frame, you're on the first. I should change currentFrameImage = frames[currentFrameNumber] to curremtFrameImage = frames[currentFrameNumber-1]